# Spark map inside flatmap to replicate cartesian join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to fuzzy join two datasets, one of the quotes and one of the sales. For arguments sake, the joining attributes are first name, surname, dob and email.

I have 26m+ quotes and 1m+ sales. Customers may not have used the accurate information for one or more of the attributes, so I'm giving them a score for each match (1,1,1,1) where all match (0,0,0,0) where none match.

So I end up with something similar to

```
q1, s1, (0,0,1,0)
q1, s2, (0,1,0,1)
q1, s3, (1,1,1,1)
q2, s1, (1,0,0,1)
...
q26000000 s1 (0,1,0,0)
```

So I think this is equivalent to a cartesian product that I'm managing my making a large number of partitions for the quotes

```
val quotesRaw = sc.textfile(....)
val quotes = quotesRaw.repartition(quotesRaw.count().toInt() / 100000)

val sales = sc.textfile(...)
val sb = sc.broadcast(sales.collect())

quotes.mapPartitions(p=> (
   p.flatMap(q => (
      sb.value.map(s =>
          q._1, s._1, ( if  q._2 == s._2 1 else 0, etc)
   )
)
```

This all works if I keep the numbers low, like 26m quotes but only 1000 sales but if I run it will all the sales it just stops responding when running

I'm running it with the following config.

```
spark-submit --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1024 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=3g --num-executors=30 \
--driver-memory 6g --class SalesMatch --deploy-mode client \
--master yarn SalesMatching-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
hdfs://cluster:8020/data_import/Sales/SourceSales/2014/09/01/SourceSales_20140901.txt \
hdfs://cluster:8020/data_import/CDS/Enquiry/2014/01/01/EnquiryBackFill_20140101.txt \
hdfs://cluster:8020/tmp/_salesdata_matches_new
```

Is there anything that jumps out as obviously incorrect here?

Comment: It depends. Creating broadcast from a RDD is an expensive process, especially when RDD is large (what is the size of a single sales record?). First you have to transfer all data to the driver and then distribute among workers. It means repeated serialization/deserialization, network traffic and cost of storing data.

Comment: @zero323 Once I've projected out the attributes I'm interested in it ends up only being 40mb for the 11m sales. The quotes ends up around 3GB after trimming to required attributes. Given these sizes on a 3 node box I don't know why its so slow. (Even accepting the q * s nature of the results

Comment: So broadcasting is unlikely to be a problem. Another part that smells fishy is Cartesian product itself.  With 100k quotes per partition and 11M sales it generates  roughly 4TB (11e11 entries) per partition if I count correctly. I would make sense to filter with low similarity right in the flatMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 100k quotes per partition and 11M sales of total size 40MB your code generates roughly 4TB data per partition so it is rather unlikely your workers can handle this and it definitely cannot be done in memory.

I assume you're interested only in close matches so it makes sense to filter early. Simplifying your code a little (as far as I can tell there is no reason to use `mapPartitions`) :

```
// Check if match is close enough, where T is type of (q._1, s._1, (...))
def isCloseMatch(match: T): Boolean = ??? 

quotes.flatMap(q => sb.value
  .map(s => (q._1, s._1, (....))) // Map as before
  .filter(isCloseMatch) // yield only close matches
)
```

General remarks:

- Creating broadcast from a RDD is an expensive process. First you have to transfer all data to the driver and then distribute among workers. It means repeated serialization/deserialization, network traffic and cost of storing data
- For relatively simple operations like this it could be a good idea to use high level Spark SQL API:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

  val salesDF: DataFrame = ???
  val salesDF: DataFrame = ???
  val featureCols: Seq[String] = ???
  val threshold: Int = ???

  val inds = featureCols // Boolean columns 
    .map(col => (quotesDF(col) === salesDF(col)).alias(s"${col}_ind"))

  val isSimilar = inds // sum(q == s) > threshold
    .map(c => c.cast("integer").alias(c.toString))
    .reduce(_ + _)
    .geq(threshold)

  val combined = quotesDF
      .join(salesDF, isSimilar, "left")
  ```

Comment: thanks for this, I'll give it a go. Is there any benefit to doing some filtering before the scoring? Would it reduce the number of sales to be checked more than above if that had been already filtered? like `.filter(q.email == s.email).map(q._1, q._2......)`

Comment: Yep, although if you have some field you want to always it would make more sense to use `Map` with this field as a key instead of linear search.  Something like `val sb = sc.broadcast(sales.map(s => (s.email, s)).collectAsMap`.